# Differentiate $\operatorname{Re}\left[\int f(z) \, dz \right]$

Tags: integration, derivatives

Given
$$
g=\operatorname{Re}\left[\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz \right], \;\;\; g \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{C}  \\
z=z_0+iz_1;
$$
what are the two derivatives (w.r.t. the real and imaginary part of z)?
$$\frac{dg}{gz_0}, \frac{dg}{gz_1}\\
$$

Comment: Differentiate with respect to what? In particular is it real or complex? Notice that the real part is not **complex** differentiable.

Comment: Differentiate with respect to z (complex), g is real.

Comment: what is $\int f(z) dz$ for a complex $z$?

Comment: Just break up $f$ into its real and imaginary part and you will see.

Comment: I think you mean $g(z)={\rm Re}(F(z))$ where $F$ is some antiderivative of $f(z)$. Since $F(z)$ is holomorphic on its domain, its real part is not holomorphic, and in particular its complex derivative does not exist. More generally, any nonconstant function $\Bbb C\to\Bbb R$ will fail to be complex differentiable.

Comment: $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz =\int_{a}^{b} f(z(t))z'(t)t $, where t is a real parameter and $z=t(a+bi)$.

Comment: @whitegreen How can $z\in\Bbb C$ be a scalar and also a path $z:[a,b]\to\Bbb C$? It can't; see my comment for the way to write what you mean.

Comment: @arctic tern, maybe I asked the question in a wrong way. Function $g$ is meant to be the Weierstrass parameterizaton (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass–Enneper_parameterization), and I am looking for $dg/dz_0$ and $dg/dz_1$, where $z=z_0+iz_1$.

Comment: I don't see "Weierstrass parametrization" anywhere in your question. You don't define $\gamma$ anywhere in your question. You don't say how $z$ can be both a scalar and a function $z:[a,b]\to\Bbb C$. The Wikipedia page says $fg^2$ must be holomorphic but otherwise does not specify any formula for $g$ in terms of $f$ like you have. So, yes, I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=u(z)+iv(z).$, where u and v are real valued. Then $\Re\int f(z) dz=\int u(z) dz$ Then use F.T.C.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Take a simple case, $f(z)=z^2$. Then $u(a+bi)=a^2-b^2$. Can you name a real- or complex-valued function whose derivative this is?

Comment: @Lubin So a^2-b^2= Re(z^2)=$(z^2+\overline{z^2))/2$. This is path-dependent, but the question did not state any contour this follows. So therefore in that case, the result is indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @LaplacianFourier. OP seems to have hoped that real-variable methods would generalize without difficulty to complex-variable calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be a smooth curve described parametrically by $z(s)=x(s)+iy(s)$, $s\in [t_0,t_1]$.  We denote $z(t_0)=z_0$ and $z(t)=z=x+iy$ for $t\in (t_0,t_1)$.

Suppose that $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is integrable on $C$.  Then, we have for the integral along $C$ for which $t_0\le s \le t<t_1$

$$\text{Re}\left(\int_{t_0}^t f(z(s))\,dz(s)\right)=\int_{t_0}^t \left(u(x(s),y(s))\frac{dx(s)}{dx}-v(x(s),y(s))\frac{dy(s)}{dx}\right)\,dt$$

Then, we can differentiate with respect to $t$ and obtain

$$\frac{d}{dt}\text{Re}\left(\int_C f(z)\,dz\right)=u(x,y)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}-v(x,y)\frac{dy(t)}{dt}$$

Answer (score 0):

My result is:
$$\frac{dg}{gz_0}=\operatorname{Re}[Xf(z)]\\
 \frac{dg}{gz_1}=\operatorname{Re}[(iY)f(z)]\\
$$
where $z=z_0+iz_1= (X+iY)t$